# How to create list of coordinates for each row in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains coordinates of several 2d points in the sequence of frames. It looks like

```
frame point_1_x point_2_x point_3_x point_1_y point_2_y point_3_y
1          0         1         1         2         3         1
2          2         3         5         1         2         3
3          8         2         3         4         5         6
```

I want to extract coordinates of given indices of points in a form of array-like structure. For example:

```
def extract_points(df, indices):
    '''
        Takes dataframe and indices of points
        returns list of coordinates of points
    '''
extract_points(example_dataset, [1,2])
output: np.array([[(0, 2), (2,1), (8, 4)], [(1,3), (3,2), (2,5)]])
```

How can I do that in a pythonic way using `numpy` and `pandas`?

Answer (score -1):

rename the columns and then groupby

```
df.columns = df.columns.str[:-2]
arr = df.stack().groupby(level=[1,0]).agg(tuple).values

array([(0, 2), (2, 1), (8, 4), (1, 3), (3, 2), (2, 5), (1, 1), (5, 3),
       (3, 6)], dtype=object)
```